# Setting a custom invoice date in CiviCRM

Tags: civicontribute, invoice

Does anyone have an elegant solution to setting a custom invoice date in CiviCRM? One of our clients likes to create invoices for the future, and would like to mark the invoice as such.

Currently, we're using a custom field and replaced the $invoice_date token with the custom field token as the date.

We're wondering if anyone else has come up with a different way?

Comment: We're having the same issue. Would like to send out invoices for future membership renewals coming due in the next 30 days, this workflow really doesn't seem supported at the moment. Are there any other solutions anyone is aware of to accommodate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are doing it correctly - to set a future date on the Invoice - I would recommend creating an New token and displaying the date - which you are already doing it - so i don't think their is any other work around

Answer (score 2):

Scheduled Reminders is the way I suspect many users provide this. Ie they create a Scheduled Reminder to go to members say 30 days before due date, with a link to the renewal page. Even if this is only set up to use Pay Later at least that way they get the data in the system that a payment is due. And of course the Contribution page then sends out the 'receipt/invoice' which if you set it up with an 'if=pay_later' to say Invoice then hey presto they generate their own invoice.

Not a solution for everybody, but definitely a standard civicrm workflow.